# Cakephp, HABTM association

Tags: cakephp

Cake newb here.

I have two tables. Users and Events. An user can subscribe to Multiple events.

What is the best way to implement this?

Do I have to create another table and link them or is there any other better approach.

If I do create a new table, how do i link them in cake model?

Comment: you should use cake model because it joins the table.when you search from table  you don't need to join it.

Comment: Start by reading the docs **[http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use HABTM relationship.

**Reason**

See users will subscribe to Multiple events and

One event have multiple users subscribed for.

So this is two way relationship. Therefore you need following tables

`users` :  To store user's data,

`events` : To store user's data,

`events_users` : To store Which user joined Which event and Vice versa(Events with n number of users)

So users_events will have 2 fields  user_id , event_id , both are foreign keys and here you dont need primary key in HABTM relationship.

Comment: couldn't have asked for a better answer. Much thanks.

Comment: @kanishka , no issues , I am glad you work with cakePHP.

Answer (score 2):

As said by jQuery.PHP.Magento.com you should use HABTM relationship but the name of the third table should be `events_users` because the table names should be in alphabetical order.

From the doc:

> Table names are in alphabetical order by convention. It is possible to
>   define a custom table name in association definition.